# O que é SimpleChanges no Angular? Seria uma API do Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
@Input() listas: IniciarFuncaoModel;

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.listas) {
      this.iniciarFuncao();
    }
  }
```

- O SimpleChanges é uma API do Angular?
- Eu entendi que, no exemplo, o SimpleChanges está tipando o parâmetro changes. (É isso?)
- Mas não entendi porque se usa o 'changes.lista' como parâmetro do if.
- Minha dúvida é: Ao tipar o parâmetro changes com o SimpleChanges, este faz com que a variável listas se torne um atributo do parâmetro changes?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O SimpleChanges é uma API do Angular?

[É a interface que representa o objeto de alterações para todas as propriedades de entrada](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-onchanges-simplechanges-example#simplechanges)

> Eu entendi que, no exemplo, o SimpleChanges está tipando o parâmetro changes. (É isso?)

Sim, esta **tipando** a variável *changes*

> Mas não entendi porque se usa o `changes.lista` como parâmetro do `if`.

`if` [é uma estrutura de decisão](https://dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/estrutura-de-decisao-se-entao-senao/), é feito uma decisão pelo visto se existe essa `lista` é como disse na primeira resposta: `lista` é um elemento de entrada de dados, quando ele contiver dados, executa a `this.iniciarFuncao();`

> Minha dúvida é: Ao tipar o parâmetro changes com o SimpleChanges, este faz com que a variável `listas` se torne um atributo do parâmetro `changes`?

Sim, ele faz com que os `input` de ***entrada*** seja analisados e permitidos a verificação de sua alteração conforme já demonstrado por você mesmo `if(changes.lista)`.

---

***`Interface`***

```
interface SimpleChanges {
    __index(propName: string): SimpleChange
}
```

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [SimpleChange Class and SimpleChanges Interface](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-onchanges-simplechanges-example#simplechanges)
- [SimpleChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges)